# Reducing repetition in my Android game

Tags: java, android

I've been writing a space invaders like game for Android and am a bit worried about how much repetition there is (going to be) in my code. In the game there are going to be EDIT: 45 enemies, each with a hit-box and shooting function. I had thought from the beginning that I should create an array of enemies that utilize a handful of methods but never made one. How can I reduce repetition in this? Or, should I simply keep going on this path?

I'm not asking for all the answers - that'd be no fun. I just need ideas for how to fix the main issues.

The problems will be made clear by the code below:

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Enemy 
{
    private int maxHealth, currentHealth, power, speedX, speedY, centerX, centerY;
    private Background bg = GameScreen.getBg1();
    private Ship ship = GameScreen.getShip();
    public  static Rect xguy1Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public static Rect xguy2Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public static Rect xguy3Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public static Rect xguy4Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public static Rect xguy5Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public static Rect xguy6Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public static Rect xguy7Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);

    private boolean isMovingRight = true;
    private boolean isMovingLeft = false;
    private boolean xguy1IsShooting = false;
    private boolean xguy2IsShooting = false;
    private boolean xguy3IsShooting = false;

    private ArrayList<EnemyProjectile> eProjectiles = new ArrayList<EnemyProjectile>();

    //Behavioral Methods
    public void update() {
    //centerX += speedY;
    //moveRight();
    //moveLeft();
    //changeMovement();
    autoFire();
    speedY = bg.getSpeedY();
    speedX = 1;
    //setBounds??? 
    xguy1Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy1.getCenterX() +22, GameScreen.xguy1.getCenterY()-1 , GameScreen.xguy1.getCenterX() + 4+22, GameScreen.xguy1.getCenterY() );
    xguy2Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy2.getCenterX()+22, GameScreen.xguy2.getCenterY() -1, GameScreen.xguy2.getCenterX() +4+22, GameScreen.xguy2.getCenterY() ); 
    xguy3Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy3.getCenterX() +22 , GameScreen.xguy3.getCenterY()-1, GameScreen.xguy3.getCenterX() +4+22, GameScreen.xguy3.getCenterY() );
    xguy4Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy4.getCenterX() +22, GameScreen.xguy4.getCenterY()-1 , GameScreen.xguy4.getCenterX() + 4+22, GameScreen.xguy4.getCenterY() );
    xguy5Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy5.getCenterX()+22, GameScreen.xguy5.getCenterY() -1, GameScreen.xguy5.getCenterX() +4+22, GameScreen.xguy5.getCenterY() ); 
    xguy6Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy6.getCenterX() +22 , GameScreen.xguy6.getCenterY()-1, GameScreen.xguy6.getCenterX() +4+22, GameScreen.xguy6.getCenterY() );
    xguy7Rect.set(GameScreen.xguy7.getCenterX() +22 , GameScreen.xguy7.getCenterY()-1, GameScreen.xguy7.getCenterX() +4+22, GameScreen.xguy7.getCenterY() );
    }

  public void autoFire()
  {
      int num = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((250 - 1) + 1));
      //System.out.println(num);
      if(num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 8 && xguy1IsShooting == false)
      {
          if(GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive == true)
          {
            xguy1Attack();
          }
      }
      if(num == 1 || num == 3 || num == 5 && xguy2IsShooting == false)
      {
          if(GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive == true)
          {
              xguy2Attack();
          }
      }
      if(num == 12 || num == 15 || num == 17 && xguy3IsShooting == false)
      {
          if(GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive == true)
          {
              xguy3Attack();
          }
      }
  }

    public void moveRight()
    {
        if(isMovingRight == true)
        {
            centerX += speedX;
            if(centerX >= 630)
            {
                isMovingRight = false;
                isMovingLeft = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void moveLeft()
    {
        if(isMovingLeft == true)
        {
            centerX -= speedX;
            if(centerX <= 10)
            {
                isMovingLeft = false;
                isMovingRight = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void changeMovement()
    {
        //causes delayed death - xguys only die after going right
        if(centerX >= 630)
        {
            isMovingRight = false;
        }
        if(isMovingRight == false)
        {
            isMovingLeft = true;
        }
    }
    public void die() 
    {

    }
  public void xguy1Attack() 
  {
      EnemyProjectile e = new EnemyProjectile(GameScreen.xguy1.getCenterX()-6, GameScreen.xguy1.getCenterY());
      eProjectiles.add(e);
      xguy1IsShooting = false;
  }
  public void xguy2Attack()
  {
      EnemyProjectile e = new EnemyProjectile(GameScreen.xguy2.getCenterX()-6, GameScreen.xguy2.getCenterY());
      eProjectiles.add(e);
      xguy2IsShooting = false;
  }

  public void xguy3Attack()
  {
      EnemyProjectile e = new EnemyProjectile(GameScreen.xguy3.getCenterX()-6, GameScreen.xguy3.getCenterY() );
      eProjectiles.add(e);
      xguy3IsShooting = false;
  }

    public int getMaxHealth() {
        return maxHealth;
    }

    public int getCurrentHealth() {
        return currentHealth;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public int getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }

    public int getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public int getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public Background getBg() {
        return bg;
    }

    public void setMaxHealth(int maxHealth) {
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void setCurrentHealth(int currentHealth) {
        this.currentHealth = currentHealth;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
        this.speedY = speedX;
    }

    public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
    }

    public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

    public void setBg(Background bg) {
        this.bg = bg;
    }

  public ArrayList getEProjectiles() {
      return eProjectiles;
      }
}
```

..................................................................

```
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Projectile {

    private int x, y, speedY;
    private boolean visible;

    private Rect r;

    public Projectile(int startX, int startY) 
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        speedY = 7;
        visible = true;

        r = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        y -= speedY;
        r.set(x, y, x + 4, y + 10);
        if (y < -10) {
           visible = false;
           r=null;
        }
        if (visible)
        {
            checkCollision();
        }
    }

    private void checkCollision()
    {
        if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy1Rect) && GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive == true)
        {
        visible = false;
        GameScreen.score += 10;
        GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive = false;
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy2Rect) && GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive = false;
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy3Rect) && GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive = false;
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy4Rect) && GameScreen.xguy4IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy4IsAlive = false;
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy5Rect) && GameScreen.xguy5IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy5IsAlive = false;
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy6Rect) && GameScreen.xguy6IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy6IsAlive = false;
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, Enemy.xguy7Rect) && GameScreen.xguy7IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy7IsAlive = false;
        }

        if(GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive == false && GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive == false 
                && GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive == false)
        {
            GameScreen.allEnemiesAreDead = true;
        }

//      if(r.intersect(GameScreen.saucer.sRect))
//      {
//          visible = false;
//          GameScreen.score += 100;
//          GameScreen.saucerIsAlive = false;
//          System.out.println("you hit the alien!");
//      }

    }


    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

}
```

I think it would be extremely inefficient if I were to continue on this path and initialize, set, and check collisions on 28 rectangles individually. In addition, creating 28 shooting functions would be a hassle.

There's also repetition in the main class of the game. The lines of periods separate chunks. Here are the snippets:

```
public static BasicEnemy xguy1, xguy2, xguy3, xguy4, xguy5, xguy6, xguy7;
...........................................................................
    static boolean xguy1IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy2IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy3IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy4IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy5IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy6IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy7IsAlive = true;
...........................................................................
            xguy1 = new BasicEnemy(420, 100);
        xguy2 = new BasicEnemy(480, 100);
        xguy3 = new BasicEnemy(360, 100);
        xguy4 = new BasicEnemy(300, 100);
        xguy5 = new BasicEnemy(240, 100);
        xguy6 = new BasicEnemy(540, 100);
        xguy7 = new BasicEnemy(600, 100);
...........................................................................
            xguy1.update();
        xguy2.update();
        xguy3.update();
        xguy4.update();
        xguy5.update();
        xguy6.update();
        xguy7.update();
..........................................................................
if(xguy1IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy1.getCenterX()-16, xguy1.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy2IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy2.getCenterX()-16, xguy2.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy3IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy3.getCenterX()-16, xguy3.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy4IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy4.getCenterX()-16, xguy4.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy5IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy5.getCenterX()-16, xguy5.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy6IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy6.getCenterX()-16, xguy6.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy7IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy7.getCenterX()-16, xguy7.getCenterY()-12);
        }
...............................................................................
            xguy1 = null;
        xguy2 = null;
        xguy3 = null;
        xguy4 = null;
        xguy5 = null;
        xguy6 = null;
        xguy7 = null;
```

ATTEMPT AT USING ARRAYS TO REDUCE REPETITION(ALL CODE BELONGS IN THE MAIN CLASS):
(FOR A 3RD TYPE OF ENEMY)

```
//make an array of 9 'piguys' that take act as basic enemies
public static BasicEnemy piguys[] = new BasicEnemy[8];

//create and set the positions of each piguy
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i ++)
        {
            piguys[num] = new BasicEnemy(180 + num*55, 200);
            num +=1;
        }
//short way of calling the update method in the Enemy class for each piguy 
for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            piguys[num2].update();
            num2 +=1;
        }
//short way to draw each piguy to the screen 
for(int f = 0; f < 9; f++)
        {
            g.drawImage(panim.getImage(), piguys[num3].getCenterX()-12, piguys[num3].getCenterY()-12);
            num3 += 1; 
        }

            //short way of nullifying each object so they can be created in the constructor
        for(int s = 0; s < 9; s++)
        {
            piguys[num3] = null;
            num +=1;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You thought correctly. You need to use some sort of collection object (like an array or list) to reduce the repetition in your code, and I applaud you for seeking a solution to this [code smell](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html). Eventually as you continue developing your game, you'll probably want better ways of configuring things like you're doing in code now. One common solution is to create a file format that contains all the configuration required per enemy (this same file will usually contain "map" data too). Your code would be able to read in the file and create enemies from the configuration (and then put them in that collection from earlier). It's not a bad idea to do what you're doing when creating a prototype, but you'll need to refactor a bunch before deciding to make it production code.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have code like

```
xguy1IsAlive...
xguy2IsAlive...
```

use an array or a `List`. Even when there are just 2 of them.

Also all the "guy"-related code should be in a single class.

```
public  static Rect xguy1Rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
private boolean xguy1IsShooting = false;
static boolean xguy1IsAlive = true;
```

All those properties belong to one guy, but it's currently spread all over the place. Multiple places are now responsible to keep track of the status of one guy. It's better if each guy keeps track of it's own status.

Some code to demonstrate how that could work:

```
class Projectile {
    // position, direction, speed, ...
    public void updatePosition() { /* based on speed & direction */ }
}

class Enemy {
    public boolean isHitBy(Projectile p) { /* check internal Rect if hit */ }
    public void updateHealthAfterHitOf(Projectile p) { /* decrease health */ }
    public boolean isAlive() { /* health > 0 ? */ }
    public boolean wantsToShoot() { /* maybe random */}
    public Projectile shootProjectile() { /* create a projectile at current position */ }
    public void updatePosition() { /* move in some direction */ }
    // move etc...
}

// the game, update() is called on each step
class Game {
    private static final int INITIAL_ENEMIES = 6;

    private final List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>(INITIAL_ENEMIES);
    private final List<Projectile> projectiles = new ArrayList<Projectile>();

    public Game() {
        for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_ENEMIES; i++)
            enemies.add(new Enemy());
    }

    public void update() {

        // handling classes on a very generic / abstract level here.
        // I don't want to know if there is a Rect in enemy or something else
        // -> not my responsibility here.

        // first move all projectiles
        for (Projectile p : projectiles) {
            p.updatePosition();
        }

        // update all enemies
        for (Iterator<Enemy> enemyIterator = enemies.iterator(); enemyIterator.hasNext();) {
            Enemy enemy = enemyIterator.next();

            // 1. check if hit, if so remove projectile
            for (Iterator<Projectile> projectilesIterator = projectiles.iterator(); projectilesIterator.hasNext();) {
                Projectile p = projectilesIterator.next();
                if (enemy.isHitBy(p)) {
                    enemy.updateHealthAfterHitOf(p);
                    // remove projectile from list
                    projectilesIterator.remove();
                }
            }

            // check if enemy survived, if not remove enemy, if yes it may shoot & move
            if (enemy.isAlive()) {
                enemy.updatePosition();
                if (enemy.wantsToShoot()) {
                    Projectile projectile = enemy.shootProjectile();
                    projectiles.add(projectile);
                }
            } else {
                enemyIterator.remove();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It requires a lot of experience to design good object oriented code and the rather abstract principles behind that are pretty hard to understand ([SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)) but you'll get the hang of it the more code you write.

---

One error

```
//make an array of 9 'piguys' that take act as basic enemies
public static BasicEnemy piguys[] = new BasicEnemy[8];
```

That creates an array of just 8 instead of 9. The thing with arrays where it's 1 less then the number you think is when you access the elements: `piguy[0]` to `piguy[7]` which makes 8 because there is a 0 element.

To make code like below safe, don't hardcode the number in there

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    piguys[num] = new BasicEnemy(180 + num * 55, 200);
    num += 1;
}
```

instead use the actual length of that array

```
    for (int i = 0; i < piguys.length; i++)
    {
        piguys[i] = new BasicEnemy(180 + i * 55, 200);
    }
```

That also allows you to change the array size without changing those hardcoded numbers in your code. When accessing the array use the index variable (`i` here) that's used in your loop. In case `num` has some other value than `i` use

```
    for (int i = 0; i < piguys.length; i++)
    {
        piguys[i] = new BasicEnemy(180 + num * 55, 200);
        num += 1;
    }
```

but keep using `piguys[i]`.

Using a different variable name like

```
for(int i...) {
}
for(int j...) {
}
for(int k...) {
}
```

is unnecessary and can lead to confusion. It's fine to use `i` for every loop. Unless they are nested like

```
for(int i...) {
    for(int j...) {
    }
}
```

One last thing: If you are just reading the array value you enhanced for loop (for-each loop) syntax because it looks even cleaner and you can't make mistakes with the index variable or length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < piguys.length; i++)
{
    piguys[i].update();
}
```

is the same as

```
for (BasicEnemy enemy : piguys)
{
    enemy.update();
}
```

Comment: I've been messing around with the code a bit using arrays, but each way I try results in a crash. Please take a look at the new edit for the code that I've tried that crashes the game.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 see updated answer, maybe that's what happened

Comment: Okay, the updated answer was extremely helpful and allowed me to use arrays to paint the enemies to the screen. However, I can't make the enemies functional using the arrays. I haven't been able to make an array of Rects properly since they have that extra (0,0,0,0) part. The console told me that the update method in the Enemy class is what's crashing things. I'm fairly sure I was using the set function in an array properly and that the actual array of Rects is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah repeating code is generally looked down upon unless it results in a significant performance increase.

I highly suggest adding them all to an array or array list. Then you can simply iterate through this array with a for loop and do collisions, updating, and drawing of the objects.

Since there are a lot of specific numbers, the adding of the items to the array might still be a little messy.

If you know how many items you want to use, I recommend an array. Otherwise an ArrayList is very handy! I recommend array over linked list because you will be accessing based on wave count (I assume).

Also, you should really look into creating a [hierarchy of objects](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3b_OOPInheritancePolymorphism.html). In my first shooter, I found it a really useful way to learn about this topic. For example, your base object is an entity that has an x, a y, an update method, and a draw method. Then you add additional objects that extend the prior object. From entity you could get an alien that specializes and adds a little bit of information. From there you could create different specialized types of aliens with different movement patterns.

Good luck and always strive to be as efficient as possible with your code :) .

Comment: "it might extend Rectangle2D" better not, [composition over inheritance](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance) :) an entity might clearly extend the functionality of a Rect2d but the other direction is not true - rect2D is not a generalized version of entity. > one should model the relation between entity and rect2d as "has a" instead of "is a"